# Android AsyncTask return dismissing a ProgressDialog after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here's the scenario:

- Account login page
- Clicking on "Sign-in" triggers a login AsyncTask
- To block the UI during network access, a ProgressDialog pops up
- Upon returning, the ProgressDialog is dismissed and the user forwarded on

This flow works very well.

Here's the problem:

- The user may rotate the screen while the AsyncTask is logging him/her in

Presently, the ProgressDialog is referenced by a class field, and dismissed using that pointer and call to .dismiss().

If the screen is rotated, though, everything crashes.

Probably because the Activity is re-created? My suspicion is that the closure around that field reference points to an object that is unreachable. What's your take?

How can I solve it reliably and elegantly? Just add `if (... != null)` checks?

**More generally, I must confess I don't understand the "best practice" to apply in cases like this:**

- Activity A triggers an AsyncTask
- The user navigates away from Activity A (back button? rotate screen? onClick that starts an Intent?)
- The AsyncTask returns when Activity A is not the topmost one anymore yet its onPostExecute() has a UI effect , note: the original delegate observer is not available anymore.
- Confused * (note: I am a beginner, so a thorough explanation would help me a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes on changing the orientation, the activity is destroyed then recreated it again.
 When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.
Add this line `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"`  to your manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name=""
    android:label="" 
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
```

Comment: Please explain how this helps in my case.

Comment: That may work, but the reasoning is wrong.  `android:configChanges` specifies which configuration changes the `Activity` will handle itself though `onConfigurationChanged().  See [android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html), including this note -- "Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change."

Comment: @iagreen, thanks for the correction. Will try to edit the reasoning based on your info. thanks

Comment: @LazyNinja the method works so well because most of the layouts are designed with widgets that auto size, so in some sense android is taking are of part of it, but I've been bitten by some custom views and this option!

Comment: Guys, this thread makes me more confused than before. You obviously know your stuff and have experience releasing apps to clients, hats off to that. But please put together, if you would, an answer digestible by somebody like me.

Comment: @iagreen It has always worked for me, so I took it for guaranteed. Thanks for the tip, it will be immensely help me when I am faced by its side effects.

Comment: @Robottinosino, Sorry about that.Did you add that line in your manifest file? Or you don't know how to do it?

Comment: I know how to add the XML attribute but I am looking for _understanding_ not just copy-and-paste... Maybe I am asking too much when I ask for an explanation as well? :( Sorry if I am..

Comment: @Robottinosino, I admire your way. Have you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html regarding the configChanges ?

Comment: I now have (thanks) and I understand why you are recommending the Activity handle its own `onConfigurationChanged()` event, basically this won't make the system kill-and-recreate. Solves the rotation problem because there won't be a "rotation side effect" as such anymore, I am upvoting you. I am still not sure how to handle late-returning AsyncTasks when the triggering Activity is not top-of-the-stack anymore.. I think this is an understanding worth having, don't you?

Comment: I think maybe I should award this answer to you, @LazyNinja, and re-open one expressed in more general terms..

Comment: @Robottinosino, no need to open a new one for the sake of giving me the answer. Maybe if you wait you will have a more convincing answer. I have always dealt with the rotation with this way an so far not experiencing side effects.

Comment: I awarded and opened a new Q. Was I able to explain myself regarding the AsyncTask conundrum though?

Comment: @LazyNinja I think he is referring to opening a question on dealing with the general nature at an `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()` method might be called after the current Activity has been destroyed for any reason, not just screen rotation

Comment: oh, I was in the middle of responding above, I will go look for the other question

Comment: @iagreen, okay I see. I am looking forward your answer in that question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).  For a detailed explanation of the details of the methods available to you.

```
android:configChanges="orientation..." tells android your application will take care of resizing the current view hierarchy.  As such, when you specify that in your manifest, your activity will not be destroyed and recreated, instead the system will just call your activity's `onConfigurationChanged()` method.  As it so happens, most of the stock widgets will resize themselves when their container changes, so if you are using basic layouts, this usually "just works" by redrawing the view hierarchy in the new format.  For custom widgets, this trick may not work.
```

The approved method is to save some configuration instance information when you are being destroyed in the `onSaveInstanceState()` method, and then recreate your state in `onCreate()`

In your case, the dialog is dismissed when then screen changes orientation, so you can either leave it that way, or reopen it in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: Fine. Do you know how to handle the call-back from the AsyncTask when "something else" moves focus away from the Activity that `.execute()`d the AsyncTask in the first place? Admittedly, a more general question than in the title..